# The extream figure notation to normal figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]
Hi, questions about the notation on the heatmap, what is going wrong and how to make it as a normal figure?

```
price_std_application = df1.groupby(['Vehicle_Country', 'MG 5'])['Net 
price'].agg('std').round(0).reset_index()
 price_std_application= price_std_application.pivot('Vehicle_Country', 'MG 
5', 'Net price')    

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,10))
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True)
f=sns.heatmap(price_std_application, annot=True, linewidths =.5, cmap=cmap, 
ax=ax)
```

I don't see anything wrong with the coding I made....

Comment: The figure looks correct. What problem is there, how would you like it instead?

Comment: I want to show 670 instead of 6.7e_02 on the plot, are there any methods?

Comment: You may use the `fmt` keyword argument as seen in [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).